# Specify intersection of groups as group_vars file in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have specific variables that need to be applied based on intersections of groups in ansible. For example, if a server is both in prod mode and has the website function, I can specify it in a playbook using `tag_function_website:&tag_mode_prod`. This is great, but what do I do if I need to create a group vars file for that intersection that has intersection specific variables (i.e. I don't want to use the same db for dev and prod, but I also have different dbs for boxes of different functions). I can't use an ampersand in a file name, so how do I create a group vars file to specify just the boxes that hit my desired intersection?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not really answering your question, rather sharing some of my experiences with Ansible.

First of all, you should consider having separate inventories for different environments (you've mention dev and prod). I've also started with single inventory initially and I found this advice absolutely astonishing: [How to Differentiate Staging vs Production](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#how-to-differentiate-staging-vs-production).

The databases that you've used as an example would be probably better referred by separate variable (i.e. hrDb and acctDb).

Comment: Rather just posting a link, please include relevant text directly in your answer. If that link ever stops working, your answer will be much less useful.

Comment: I do, but this is all done through ec2.py using dynamic inventories in ec2 as recommended by Ansible docs. I still need a way to differentiate on the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar goal, and I was able to come up with something that seems to work.  This relies on Marcin's observation, but I'll flesh out some details.  If you split the inventories between prod and stg then you can do the following...

In your prod inventory, define the groups:

```
[prod_website]
#hosts go here...

[website:children]
prod_website
```

Then in your stg inventory, define the analogous groups:

```
[stg_website]
#hosts go here...

[website:children]
stg_website
```

Then, in your group_vars, you would create the group-intersection vars under prod_website and stg_website.  When you invoke ansible and specify which inventory to use, it will pull in the group-intersection vars that you want, but in your playbooks you can still reference the general website group, which is present in both prod and stg.